# Bootstrap columns re-sizing to single row when it shouldn't

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am teaching myself how to use Bootstrap columns, ran into a small problem.

When I resize my browser to the smallest size possible (or even halfway through, really) to make the css kick in the columns, instead of resizing to fit in 4 images for row it just becomes a single string of images like so:

[image: Image example]

Here is my html, I am using bootstrap 3. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<section class="container" style="padding-bottom: 60px;">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Passion, precision and simplicity</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetur adipiscing</a> elit. Maecenas metus nulla, 
                commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor 
                convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas 
                metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Ut enim massa, 
                sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, 
                <strong>commodo a sodales sed</strong>, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. 
                Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, <strong>iaculis ac massa</strong>.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed,
                dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et <a href="#">lacus neque</a>. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis 
                et, iaculis ac massa.
            </p>

            <!-- divider -->
            <div class="divider styleColor">
                <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
            </div>

            <!-- brands -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/2.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/3.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/4.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/5.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/6.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/7.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/8.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
                <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/people/woman.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You have too many columns in the row with the images. Max is 12 per row.

Comment: Your `.col-md-3`, according to BS docs, is a column set at the `md` breakpoint. If you want columns for their tablet, you'd use `.col-sm-3` or whatever flavor you want. Depending on what you need, you can mix/match columns and breakpoints, like this: `.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4 .col-md-3` which would equate to two columns XS, 3 columns SM and 4 columns MD (and LG). Take some time to really read their docs, it'll pay dividends in any responsive design.

Comment: I will, sorry for the dumb-ish question.

Comment: There are no dumb questions, only dumb answers. This question is not one of those at all. All the answers so far have relevance and good information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the smaller breakpoints like `col-sm-*` to make the vertical stacking happen at a narrower width. Or, you can use `col-xs-*` to make the columns never stack.

http://bootply.com/4JKga3vGjl

Note: Contrary to popular opinion, there's no problem having columns that total more than 12 units in a single `row`. It simply causes the row to wrap. From the docs (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)..

> "If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of
>   extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line"

Comment: Wish I could vote your answer twice, for the 12 columns point. Some folks get pretty dogmatic about that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look [at the doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

And in a row, you should have only, on total, the number 12.
Like 4 times col-md-3, or 2x4+2x2, etc

In your case, that could be something like this.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="container" style="padding-bottom: 60px;">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Passion, precision and simplicity</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetur adipiscing</a> elit. Maecenas metus nulla, 
                commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor 
                convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas 
                metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Ut enim massa, 
                sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, 
                <strong>commodo a sodales sed</strong>, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. 
                Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, <strong>iaculis ac massa</strong>.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed,
                dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et <a href="#">lacus neque</a>. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis 
                et, iaculis ac massa.
            </p>

            <!-- divider -->
            <div class="divider styleColor">
                <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
            </div>

            <!-- brands -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/2.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/3.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/4.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/5.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/6.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/7.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/brands/8.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
                <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/demo/people/woman.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: There's no problem with the columns totaling more than 12.. "If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line" ___ http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to add `col-sm-3` and `col-xs-3` in addition to `col-md-3`, to handle your columns in lower sizes.

Check this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/4rPxAr5Ti0).

Answer (score 1):

you are using the classes "col-md-..." this targets medium devices.
To set up your layout for smaller devices use "col-xs"

Note, that you can use both "col-xs-12 col-md-6" will display the element in 100% width on small devices and 50% width on medium devices and up.

In the bootstrap grid system, there are only 12 colums per row.
you are trying to use only 12 per row.

check out http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic